# Construction of infinite list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, infinite-sequence

I have two things for the desired infinite list: its first element

```
x :: A
```

and function which generates the next element

```
f :: [A] -> A
```

What's the best (most idiomatic? fastest?) way to create infinite list? I mean

```
xs = x : f [x] : f [x, f [x]] : f [x, f [x], f [x, f [x]]] : ...
```

Comment: Are you searching for the [unfoldr](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) function?

Comment: unfoldr has type `unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]`, so you mean returning "current" whole list as `b` and next single element as `a`? Thanks, this really seems to work =)

Comment: But is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: Do you need the whole list in every iteration? (This will slow down alot.) Or is a accumulator value sufficient? Then there is another function called [mapAccumL/R](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL) that may help you.

Comment: `infiniteList = x:map f (tail $ inits infiniteList)` where `x` is the first element and `f` is the function to be applied to each prefix.

Comment: @Florian: yes, the function needs the whole list (more exactly, it needs some elements from the list, but they can be located randomly).

Comment: @is7s: oh, really nice method, and no function signature change needed  :)

Comment: @is7s: would you put this as an answer? And please add a note about its performance, through I don't need a speed up now, it's never a bad thing.

Comment: You can use iterate: `map head $ iterate (\l -> f l : l) [x]`. Note that `l` is reversed (`l` is the list of previous elements), so maybe `\l -> f (reverse l) : l`.

Comment: To make this a little bit mathematically cleaner, forget `x` and just use `f`. The first element is then the result of `f []`.  Then in `constructInf` you no longer need the `tail`.  I also suspect, based on intuition, that your `f` will be simpler in this case as well.

Comment: @luqui: probably a good idea in general case, but not in mine: the first element is special and can't be simply generate by the same function `f` as other elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function you want can be implemented as:

```
constructInf :: ([a] -> a) -> a -> [a]
constructInf f x = xs
  where xs = x:map f (tail $ inits xs)
```

The performance of `consrtuctInf` depends on the performance of it's argument function `f`. Assuming `f` takes O(N) time, then `constructInf` will take O(M*N) time, where M is the number of elements from the result of `constructInf` that you will inspect.

Comment: Worthy of note is also the related [`Data.Vector.constructN`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/latest/doc/html/Data-Vector.html#v:constructN) which does the same thing for finite vectors, with potentially much better performance due to O(1) random access and using mutation under the hood.

Comment: And what about memory usage? Won't `inits` create many sublists which all be in use and not GC'ed?

Comment: Just to note: the time in this case will be `O(M^2)` 'cause `N` changes from `1` to `M`.

Comment: @hammar: thanks, this will be worth remembering when current code will be too slow.

Comment: @chersanya for memory usage, yes `inits` will create many intermediate lists. However, these intermediate lists will only be constructed when needed and will be garbage-collected after they've been used. I'm not sure really if list fusion can do anything here.

Answer (score 1):

You want [`iterate`](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Prelude.html#v%3aiterate).

```
take 10 $ iterate (+1) 0

= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

If you need the whole list so far, and don't mind getting it reversed, you can do this:

```
mkl f x0 = x0 : unfoldr (\xs -> let x = f xs in Just (x, x:xs)) [x0]
```

If you need the whole list so far, and you want it in order, it will be really inefficient, but you can do this:

```
mkl' f x0 = x0 : unfoldr (\xs -> let x = f xs in Just (x, xs ++ [x])) [x0]
```

But I'm not sure why you need the whole list instead of just the last element.

Comment: Oh, you want the whole list so far in each iteration?  `iterate` just gets the previous element.